# Importance sampling in r to calculate mean

Tags: r, distribution, sample, normal-distribution, montecarlo

I am given the following distribution:
f(x) = e^{-x*erf(x)}/1.14

I am asked to compute the standard deviation of f(x); I have trouble below computing E(x^2) which should equal approx 1.80 but i got 1.70. Once i get that i can use E(x^2)-E(x)^2 to get variance and sd.

```
library(extraDistr)
library(vgam)
set.seed(50)
N = 1000
x = rhnorm(N,sigma=2.5) # Sample x samples from the proposal distribution h(x)
#plot(x)
h = dhnorm(x,sigma=2.5) # Evaluate h(x)
g = rep(0,N)
g[x>=0] = x[x>=0]    # Evaluate g(x)
f = function(x) {        # Evaluate f(x)
  f.x = rep(0,length(x))
  f.x[x>=0] =  exp((-x[x>=0])*erf(x[x>=0]))/1.140741
  return(f.x)
} 
mean((g*f(x)/h))^2 #E(X)^2
mean((g*f(x)/h)^2) #E(x^2)
```

if i change my h=dnorm(x^2,...) the mean gets huge. I am not sure what i did wrong.

Comment: The sample value of E(X^2) that you observe (1.70) seems compatible with its population value (1.80): am I wrong?

Comment: Which if the two articles referenced in the half-normal of `extraDistr` would you say is more applicable to our understanding here?